# Binding DataTable object with ListBox in WPF vs Binding DataTable object with ListBox in Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatable, listbox

I learned this in Windows Forms Application following a youtube tutorial but I'm having a hard time implementing the same approach in the WPF.

```
private void PopulateNames()
{
    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connection_string))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM namesTable", connection))
    {
        DataTable namesTable = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(namesTable);
        Debug.Write(namesTable.AsDataView());

        namesListBox.DisplayMemberPath = "name";
        namesListBox.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
        namesListBox.ItemsSource = namesTable.AsDataView();
    }
}
```

And the XAML for the `ListView` is

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="name" x:Name="namesListBox" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="209" Margin="90,59,0,0" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="341" SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged"/>
</Grid>
```

And I cannot understand what is wrong I followed the MSDN and many questions on stackoverflow about this but since I'm a newbie to this maybe I didn't get the answer I was looking for.

So my question is How Data Binding is different in **WPF and Windows Form Applications** thought the implementation in the WinForms Application was pretty straight forward, I cannot figure out how to populate the `ListBox` with the entries from the database.

Comment: If you called the `PopulateNames` method this should works. What is your problem?

Comment: Have you tried removing the Itemsource DP from the xaml and checking.
What is the Window DataContext set to??

Comment: @user2946329 you saved the day man, I was not calling it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has not any problem and it should works. Probably you missed calling the `PopulateNames` method.

Also here you don't need `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` and `DisplayMemberPath="name"` in your XAML because you have set it in your code behind.

If you want to do it in your XAML you could do it like this:

```
private void PopulateNames()
{
    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connection_string))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM namesTable", connection))
    {
        DataTable namesTable = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(namesTable);
        Debug.Write(namesTable.AsDataView());
        DataContext = namesTable.AsDataView();
    }
}
```

And in your XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="name" SelectedValuePath="Id" 
         x:Name="namesListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="209" 
         VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```